# Flutter: Open iOS iPhone Settings page

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to open Location settings page in iOS using flutter? I don't want a native solution.

Comment: Did you try with url_launcher (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) and pass string? "App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"

Comment: It only opens Settings and not the location page.

Comment: How to handle in android ?

Comment: Don't use "App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION", otherwise your app will get rejected.

Comment: @EstevãoLucas Thanks for telling me, do you know any better way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

I've used this package, does the job so far:
https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings

```
AppSettings.openLocationSettings()
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Nick Ponomar mentioned, [App Settings package from pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings) is a great choice.

I just want to mention that it also offers `openAppSettings` method, which leads you to the settings screen/page for your app (i.e. the one that called the method `openAppSettings`). That settings screen contains all permission which your app requested since it was installed, whether they are enabled or disabled.

Example of app settings screen for WhatsApp:
[image: Example of app settings screen - from techknowzone.com]