# Flutter: How to open iphone settings page in flutter?

Tags: iphone, flutter

I need to open the settings page of iphone. I used code including 
"App-Prefs:root=Privacy"  and AppStore rejected the project. What will be the solution for this problem in flutter.

Comment: Which specific setting you want to open

Comment: @Lakhwinder Singh , I need to open lockscreen page actually. If not then at least settings page.

Comment: Why do you want to navigate to lock screen

Comment: @ Lakhwinder Singh , my app has feature to change lockscreen of the iphone and as apple doesn't permit to change it directly, I need to minimize the steps for users to change the lockscreen by directly navigating to that page. If it can't be done then opening settings page or wallpaper page is also enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53543905/6374527

Comment: @George, there is no solution in that link you provided. The solution provided is rejected by the apple as I have mentioned in my description.

Comment: @Lakhwinder Singh, can you help me please ?

Comment: have you tried plugin `app_setting`? Maybe you can try this [app_setting](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using [app_settings](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings) should this functionality to worked. I suggest trying this plugin in your end.

Android:

[image]

iOS:

[image]