# Opening permissions settings for an app on iOS in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to open the settings page containing all permissions given to an app programatically. Using `AppSettings.openAppSettings()` [seems to be the best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543905/flutter-open-ios-iphone-settings-page), however when I try this, the settings app is opened without going to the specific subpage. I have also tried `openAppSettings()` from the `permission_handler` package with the same result. How would I fix this?

Alternatively, going directly to Settings -> Privacy -> Local Network would also work, but I have not been able to find a solution for that. `SystemSettings.privacy()` is the closest i can find, but this also only opens the settings app without doing any further navigation.

I hope someone with more insight can shed some light on this problem.

The following versions were used

- Flutter 2.0.2
- `app_settings` 4.1.0
- `system_settings` 2.0.0
- `permission_handler` 5.1.0+2 (using newer versions cause conflicts with other dependencies, so I cannot go any higher)
- iOS 14.2

Comment: You can only open the root settings page for your app.  There is no way to go to a specific sub-page or any other preferences page

Comment: Well that sucks, but thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: I faced the same issue. @Paulw11 rights, so what I did is to notify the users (with a snackbar in my case) that they have to "Please grant contacts access permissions" for instance. Then, right after the message, I run openAppSettings(). So basically the user understands what are the missing permissions and only then I take them to the root settings. I think it's very user friendly.