# In flutter app is there any way to open Settings>Privacy&Security>Tracking page from our Own application?

Tags: flutter, security, tracking, system-setting, maid

I want to open Settings>Privacy&Security>Tracking page on Button click.

It opens own app security page but I want to open Settings>Privacy&Security>Tracking. Is there way to open direct Tracking page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Open iOS iPhone Settings page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543905/flutter-open-ios-iphone-settings-page)